# Форма с полями CheckboxSelectMultiple в CreateView непроходит валидацию

Tags: jquery, python-3.x, ajax, django

Модели:

```
class Resume(models.Model):

title = models.CharField(_('Title'), max_length=100)
other_skills = models.CharField(_('Other skills'), max_length=200)
hobbies = models.CharField(_('Hobbies'), max_length=200)
about = models.CharField(_('About'), max_length=400)
education = models.ManyToManyField(Education, related_name='educations', verbose_name=_('Education'))
skill = models.ManyToManyField(Skill, related_name='skills', verbose_name=_('Skills'))
job = models.ManyToManyField(Job, related_name='jobs', verbose_name=_('Jobs'))

class Education(models.Model):

period_edu = models.CharField(_('Period education'), max_length=50)
name_institution = models.CharField(_('Name of institution'), max_length=100)
faculty = models.CharField(_('Faculty'), max_length=100)
form_study = models.CharField(_('Form of study'), max_length=30)
```

Все модели приводить не буду, остальные модели подобные Education для МТМ полей Resume.

Форма:

```
class ResumeCreateUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = Resume
    fields = (
        'title',
        'other_skills',
        'hobbies',
        'about',
        'education',
        'skill',
        'job'
    )
    widgets = {
        'title': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        'other_skills': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'rows': '5'}),
        'hobbies': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'rows': '5'}),
        'about': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'rows': '5'}),
        'education': forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
        'skill': forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
        'job': forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
    }

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(ResumeCreateUpdateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    if self.instance.pk:
        resume = Resume.objects.get(pk=self.instance.pk)
        self.fields['education'].queryset = resume.education.all()
        self.fields['skill'].queryset = resume.skill.all()
        self.fields['job'].queryset = resume.job.all()
    else:
        self.fields['education'].queryset = Resume.objects.none()
        self.fields['skill'].queryset = Resume.objects.none()
        self.fields['job'].queryset = Resume.objects.none()
```

Вью:

```
class ResumeCreateView(CreateView):
model = Resume
form_class = ResumeCreateUpdateForm
template_name = 'dashboard_worker/dashboard_resume_create.html'

def get_context_data(self, *, object_list=None, **kwargs):
    context = super(ResumeCreateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['w_pk'] = self.kwargs['w_pk']
    return context

def form_valid(self, form, **kwargs):
    response = super(ResumeCreateView, self).form_valid(form)
    obj = form.save(commit=False)
    account = AccountWorker.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['w_pk'])
    account.resume.add(obj)
    account.save()
    return response

def get_success_url(self, **kwargs):
    return reverse_lazy('dashboard_worker:dashboard_worker_resume', kwargs={'pk': self.kwargs['w_pk']})
```

В шаблоне который рендерит вью отображаю форму, в ней добавил кнопки добавления моделей education, skill и job, повесил обработчики отправляющие посредством ajax(jquery) в другую вью, которая возвращает пустую форму модели education, skill и job, эти формы можно заполнить и нажать добавить и данные добавятся в текущую форму заполнения резюме т.е ajax вью возвращает данные созданного education, skill, job и добавляет в html форму:

```
<label class="form-check-label" for="id_education_47"><input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="education" value="47" id="id_education_47" checked="">ваип</label>
```

Но при сохранении формы происходит ошибка:

```
Select a valid choice. 46 is not one of the available choices.
```

И так для каждого поля education, skill, job.

Comment: Путем долгих копаний выяснил, что проблема заключается в блоке init в форме ResumeCreateUpdateForm. Если убрать этот блок, то для разных пользователей при создании резюме будут выводиться все существующие education, skill и job (причем всех пользователей), подскажите пожалуйста как выводить пустые поля education, skill и job, избежав ошибки:
Select a valid choice. 46 is not one of the available choices.

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему используя костыль(правильного решения так и не нашел). Добавил еще одну форму без использования блока инит:

```
class ResumeForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Resume
    fields = (
        'title',
        'other_skills',
        'hobbies',
        'about',
        'education',
        'skill',
        'job'
    )
    widgets = {
        'title': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        'other_skills': forms.Textarea(
            attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'rows': '5'}
        ),
        'hobbies': forms.Textarea(
            attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'rows': '5'}
        ),
        'about': forms.Textarea(
            attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'rows': '5'}
        ),
        'education': forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
        'skill': forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
        'job': forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
    }
```

И во вью добавил еще одну проверку валидности(новой формой) в блоке form_invalid:

```
    def form_invalid(self, form, **kwargs):
    pre_form = ResumeForm(self.request.POST)
    if pre_form.is_valid():
        obj = pre_form.save()
        account = AccountWorker.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['w_pk'])
        account.resume.add(obj)
        account.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
    else:
        return super(ResumeCreateView, self).form_invalid(form, **kwargs)
```

Такое решение помогло пройти валидацию